# Variables incorrect; fraction calculator; JAVA

Tags: java, fractions

I have my code here which i have posted on here before and have been helped before.  The variables seem to be incorrect and i am unsure why. I entered the fraction 1/2 + 3/4 and am getting the answer 8/4. i know it has to do with the variables because when i run the debugger it says that "a" = 1, 'b'= 1, 'c'=4, and 'd'=4.  'a' and 'd' are correct in the way i want them, going from 'a' through 'd' from left to right. i think i know where the problem is but i dont know how to fix it.  I think the problem with 'b' has to do with this line of code

```
b = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

Here is my full code

import java.util.*;

```
public class Calculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Please enter two fractions to add, subtract, multiply, or divide\nor\nType             'quit' to exit the program.");
Boolean on = true;
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
while (on) {
    String input = console.nextLine();
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        on = false;
    } else
        System.out.println(run(input));
}
}
public static String run(String input) {
int indexOfSecondSpace = 0;
int indexOfOperation = 0;
String firstNumber = "0";
String secondNumber = "0";
int beginning = input.indexOf(" ") + 1;
int end = input.indexOf(" ", beginning);
String operator = input.substring(beginning, end);
if (input.contains("+") == true) {
indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("+");
} else if (operator.equals("-")) {
indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("-");
} else if (operator.equals("*")) {
indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("*");
} else if (operator.equals("/")) {
indexOfOperation = input.indexOf("/");
}
firstNumber = (input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" ")));
secondNumber = (input.substring(beginning + 1));
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int d = 0;  
if (firstNumber.contains("/")) {
a = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.substring(0,firstNumber.indexOf("/")));
b = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.substring(0,firstNumber.indexOf("/")));
} else if (!firstNumber.contains("/"))
a = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" ")));
b = Integer.parseInt("1");
{
    if (secondNumber.contains("/")) {
    c = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/")+1));
    d = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/")+1));
    } else if (!secondNumber.contains("/")) {
    c = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.length()));
    d = Integer.parseInt("1");
    }
}
String res = calculate(input, a, b, c, d) ;
return res;
}
public static String calculate(String input, int a, int b, int c, int d){
if (input.contains ("+"))
{
    System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*d + b*c)+"/" +(b*d));
}
else if  (input.contains("-"))
{
    System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*d - b*c)+ "/" +(b*d));
}
else if (input.contains("/"))
{
    System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*d)/(b*c)+ "/" +(b*d));
}
else if (input.contains("*"))
{
    System.out.println("your answer is " + (a*c) +"/" +(b*d));
}
return input;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following in your code

```
c = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/")+1));
d = Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.substring(secondNumber.indexOf("/")+1));
```

Why would you expect c and d to have different values?

Also of note

```
d = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

Could be rewritten as

```
d = 1;
```

Comment: so how would i go around fixing this to make it print the output i want it too. sorry i am still really new to java. help is apreciated. Thanks